# How do I return data from fetch and display in div?

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

For example here is the content of a JSON on a remote URL:

`{ "title": "The title", "description": "The description" }`

Could you please help with this:

- I want to fetch json data from remote url (async task).
- When the value is returned, I want to display the title (json) in a DIV.

The function below displays "[object Promise]" in my DIV.

```
async buildWidget() {
    var id = "whatever"
    let data = await fetch('getItem.php?id=' + id + '&callback=getJSONP');
    var json = data.json();
    
    return json.title;
}
```

No JQuery please.

Thanks

Comment: `json` is an async method. You also need to `await` it before reading fields from it.

Comment: 1. Put an `await` keyword before `data.json()`. 2. Call the `buildWidget` function as: `buildWidget().then(title => { /* show title in div */}).catch(err => { /* handle error*/})`.

Comment: I see, the main problem was how I call the function. Thanks

Comment: If the context in which you call `buildWidget()` is also async, then you can simply use `await buildWidget()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` method returns a promise, so just `await` and get the `JSON` response from it. You can then simply get the properties like `data.title` or `data.description` and render then to the DOM.

```js
async function buildWidget() {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
  const data = await response.json();

  document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = data.title;
}

buildWidget();
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use await on .json() as it is asynchronous I.e.

```
async buildWidget() {
    var id = "whatever"
    let data = await fetch('getItem.php?id=' + id + '&callback=getJSONP');
    var json = await data.json();
    
    return json.title;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `.json()` returns an promise and then also needs to `await` for it.

Second: `async` functions are asynchronouse they return an promise.

```
async buildWidget() {
    var id = "whatever"
    let data = await fetch('getItem.php?id=' + id + '&callback=getJSONP');
    var json = await data.json();
    
    return json.title;
}

buildWidget().then(title => {
   console.log(title)
})
```